# bfgminer (lxterminal:1024): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Tags: gtk

I'm getting "(lxterminal:1024): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:" error when trying to run bfgminer on startup in the rc.local.

If I run rc.local it starts fine so seem to be an issue with the startup.

The command i'm using is "lxterminal -e /usr/lib/bfgminer/bfgminer -o stratum+tcp://url:3333 -u username.worker -p password"

Can someone please help me to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the time `rc.local` runs, the X window system (which supplies `$DISPLAY`) has not yet started. If possible, replace `lxterminal` with a shell script that logs to a file.

Comment: The only thing that appear in the log it "(lxterminal:1024): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:", is there a more in depth log than "exec 2> /tmp/rc.local.log      # send stderr from rc.local to a log file
exec 1>&2                      # send stdout to the same log file
set -x                         # tell sh to display commands before execution"

Comment: I meant "don't use lxterminal". The supporting X window system has Not been started when rc.local runs.